# How to put Element text on one row in ListActivity with this

Tags: android

I am using this code to retrieve a set of game titles platform and release dates:

```
public class HtmlparserExampleActivity extends ListActivity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ArrayList<String> gameList = new ArrayList<String>();

        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.gamespy.com/index/release.html").get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Get all td's that are a child of a row - each game has 4 of these
        Elements games = doc.select("tr > td.indexList1, tr > td.indexList2");
        // Iterator over those elements     
        ListIterator<Element> postIt = games.listIterator();          
        while (postIt.hasNext()) {     
            // Add the game text to the ArrayList     
            gameList.add(postIt.next().text());     
            Log.v(TAG, games.text());
        }         

        String[] items = new String[gameList.size()];
        gameList.toArray(items);
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
    }
}
```

It works perfectly like this. The only problem is if you go to the webpage I'm retrieving the items from. It displays the game title, release date, and the platform all on separate list rows.

How could I put the title, platform release date and all in one row for EACH game I retrieve?

EDIT - ClassCast Exception error:

> 08-15 16:35:12.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21589): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   08-15 16:35:12.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21589):
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
>   cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams 08-15
>   16:35:12.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21589):     at
>   android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1790) 08-15
>   16:35:12.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21589):     at
>   android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1759) 08-15
>   16:35:12.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21589):     at
>   android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:656) 08-15
>   16:35:12.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21589):     at
>   android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:716) 08-15
>   16:35:12.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21589):     at
>   android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1609) 08-15
>   16:35:12.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21589):     at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1800) 08-15
>   16:35:12.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21589):     at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:9581)

Here is the code I constructed following the tutorial and your answer:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ArrayList<GameRelease> gameList = new ArrayList<GameRelease>();

    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.gamespy.com/index/release.html").get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Get all td's that are a child of a row - each game has 4 of these
    Elements games = doc.select("tr > td.indexList1, tr > td.indexList2");
    // Iterator over those elements     
    ListIterator<Element> postIt = games.listIterator();          
    while (postIt.hasNext()) {     
        // ...

        while (postIt.hasNext()) {     
            // Add the game text to the ArrayList     
            String name = postIt.next().text();
            String platform = postIt.next().text();
            String genre = postIt.next().text();
            String releaseDate = postIt.next().text();
            gameList.add(new GameRelease(name, platform, genre, releaseDate));
            Log.v(TAG, games.text());
        }

        this.setListAdapter(new GameReleaseAdapter(this, gameList));
    }         
}

private class GameReleaseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GameRelease> {

    private ArrayList<GameRelease> items;

    public GameReleaseAdapter(Context context,  ArrayList<GameRelease> items) {
        // TODO: make a layout for each item which you'd call (for example) itemLayout
        super(context, R.layout.item, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO: return an item view styled however you want or as shown in the tutorial
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }
        GameRelease o = items.get(position);
        TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
        TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
        tt.setText(o.getName());
        bt.setText(o.getReleaseDate());
        return bt;
    }
}
}
```

EDIT - Layout item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</LinearLayout>
```

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toptext"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/bottomtext"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it's doing is getting each HTML `<td>` (table cell) as a separate String as opposed to each `<tr>`. You probably already know this.

You probably want to make a custom adapter that takes in multiple Strings (a couple elements from your List), and has an overrided `getView()` to display the contents exactly however you want them (lined up as if in a table, or in two-line format, with bigger text showing the game name, and smaller text saying "Platform: X Genre: Y Release Date: Z", for two examples).

[Here is a tutorial on making your own custom list adapter](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/) (this is as opposed to your current `ArrayAdapter<String>`).

Let's have an object, `GameRelease`, for each item (what you probably want in place of Orders in the tutorial):

```
public class GameRelease {

    private String name;
    private String platform;
    private String genre;
    private String releaseDate;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPlatform() {
        return platform;
    }

    public String getReleaseDate() {
        return releaseDate;
    }

    public String getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public GameRelease(String name, String platform, String genre, String releaseDate) {
        this.name = name;
        this.platform = platform;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    }
}
```

Then, I would write an adapter that looks something like this, taking your new GameRelease object:

```
private class GameReleaseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GameRelease> {

    private ArrayList<GameRelease> items;

    public GameReleaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Order> items) {
        // TODO: make a layout for each item which you'd call (for example) itemLayout
        super(context, R.layout.itemLayout, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO: return an item view styled however you want or as shown in the tutorial
    }
}
```

Now once you have that all set, you can instead of your while loop adding only one String element per `<td>`, take the GameRelease and fill it with multiple `<td>` elements (four, in the same order the site gives them), ex:

```
ArrayList<GameRelease> gameList = new ArrayList<GameRelease>();

Document doc = null;
try {
    doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.gamespy.com/index/release.html").get();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// Get all td's that are a child of a row - each game has 4 of these
Elements games = doc.select("tr > td.indexList1, tr > td.indexList2");
// Iterator over those elements     
ListIterator<Element> postIt = games.listIterator();   

while (postIt.hasNext()) {     
    // Add the game text to the ArrayList     
    String name = postIt.next().text();
    String platform = postIt.next().text();
    String genre = postIt.next().text();
    String releaseDate = postIt.next().text();
    gameList.add(new GameRelease(name, platform, genre, releaseDate));
    Log.v(TAG, games.text());
}

this.setListAdapter(new GameReleaseAdapter(this, gameList));
```

Just a note: since `ArrayAdapter<T>` has a constructor for `List<T>` (instead of `T[]`), which is a superclass of `ArrayList<T>`, you can pass in your `ArrayList<String>` or `ArrayList<GameRelease>` instead of converting it into an array.

Comment: Just what i am looking for. What if i dont want the <Order>?

Comment: One immediate problem is you didn't need two while loops. Edit: Actually it might affect the end result...

Comment: Next problem is the use of your main layout. I think you want to make your own layout *just for the item itself* using perhaps a TwoLineListItem, or just a couple TextViews in a horizontal LinearLayout. Your exception appears to come from your layout.

Comment: Isnt the row the layout for the item? Thats where the text views for the title and all lies. What should the item layout be for? And could you post an update in your answer. But i did a Log.V and everything works correctly except the error above. I think its coming from   super(context, R.layout.main, items); inside the GameReleaseAdapter class

Comment: What should the layout be like? I just made one called item with just a horizontal LinearLayout and it gave the same error. What do you think it is?

Comment: Yes, so then you should *change* `R.layout.main` in the super call (that's why I wrote the comment!) to the name of the layout file you made. Say you named it listItem.xml, you'd change it to `R.layout.listItem`.

Comment: Layout item i just set it to a horizontal linearlayout. But it still wont work. I have nooo idea what im doing wrong

Comment: Did you try `super(context, R.layout.row, items);` ??

Comment: Yeah ive tried that got this error //08-15 18:09:46.900: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(23586): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
. Check out my edit with the item.xml and row.xml

Comment: @coder_For_Life22 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2504/discussion-between-ribose-and-coder-for-life22)

Comment: Oh! The most likely cause of that looks like you just returned the wrong view from getView(). You must return `v` from getView() otherwise it tries to cast that to something it cannot.
Also, just a note, you should to use the same layout in the super() call as the one you inflate in getView(), but that's not important because you are overwriting ArrayAdapter's getView() to show it. You don't need more than one XML layout for item. row.xml looks sufficient for what you want. (I'm posting here because you never came to chat... :P)

Answer (score 0):

You could just iterate over the <tr>s, and then in the loop iterate over <td>s and build the string along the way, pushing it out only when you've got all <td>s from the row.